Is there any way to explicitly control batch size in Mulesoft to Salesforce connection
Let's say I am using the Mule Salesforce connector and am invoking a data load job using Bulk API. I know Salesforce will chunk out the load into its default number of batches (eg 200 for batch loads, 2000 for bulk api, etc)
But is there a way in Mulesoft to set an arbitrary batch size for a load job using the Salesforce connector (be it bulk or bulk v2)? Say I wanted to run my load with a batch size of 300 instead of 2k. In DataLoader, I could just modify the batch size directly. Is there a feature like this in Mule's Salesforce connector?
